# Set value of character_set_client to utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, collation, utf-8

I'm trying to convert my DB to `utf8mb4` following [this guide](http://mths.be/utf8mb4). I have set:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
collation_server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8mb4
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

But the value of `character_set_client` and `character_set_results` still won't change to utf8mb4.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8               |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8               |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get those values set to utf8mb4?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Disclosure:** I’m the author of [How to support full Unicode in MySQL databases](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4), the guide you’re following.

1. Where did you save the modified settings? Check where `mysqld` loads the default options from. It’s usually `/etc/my.cnf` ([as mentioned in the guide](http://mths.be/utf8mb4)) but it may be different on your system. Run the following command to find out:

   ```
   $ mysqld --help --verbose 2> /dev/null | grep -A1 'Default options'
   Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
   /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
   ```
2. Did you restart `mysqld` by running `mysqld restart` after making the changes?

Comment: 1. I saved changes in `\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini`. I was unable to run `mysqld --help --verbose 2> /dev/null | grep -A1 'Default options'` - as it gives the following error: `'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I'm new to this stuff, so I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: 2. I did restart mysqld, and after it gives me the following warnings: 2014-02-19 10:25:17 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix character_set_client instead of character-set-client-handshake is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2014-02-19 10:25:17 0 [Warning] mysqld: ignoring option '--character-set-client-handshake' due to invalid value 'utf8mb4'

Comment: Why do you have `skip-character-set-client-handshake` in your config file? It’s a command-line option, not a variable.

Comment: I had to re-install local server; walked through your guide again and everything worked out. I appreciate your response and help. I will come back to your answer and upvote it as soon as I have enough reps to do so.

Comment: I tried this but still `character_set_client`, `character_set_connection`, `character_set_results`, `collation_connection` is shown as `utf8`. Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Setting `default-character-set=utf8mb4` in MySQL config file is not enough. `character_set_client` remains set to `utf8`, at least in mysql 5.6. Also in `mysqldump` produces `character_set_client` explicitly set to `utf8` as a wrapper around each CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: I had to recreate the DB again.

Answer (score 3):

I've also followed that guide, however, the same issue appeared again.
The actual issue lies in command used to create the DB as it takes `DEFAULT CHARACTER` as an argument and if that is not passed while execution a default character set is passed which is not `utfmb4`.

Below are the steps that I followed to fix it:

1. Create a dummy database with `utf8mb4` character set.

   ```
   create database `your_db_name_dummy`
     DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
     DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
   ```
2. Copy actual structure and data to this dummy database from actual database

   `mysqldump -uroot -proot_password your_db_name | mysql -uroot -proot_password your_db_name_dummy`
3. Drop current database

   ```
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
   DROP DATABASE your_db_name;
   ```
4. Create new database

   ```
   create database `your_db_name`
     DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
     DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
   ```
5. Finally, put the table structure and data back to the original database

   `mysqldump -uroot -proot_password your_db_name_dummy | mysql -uroot -proot_password your_db_name`

If you're going to use above mentioned procedure then please make sure to carefully read below mentioned lines too.

Prerequisites and my status quo:

- Backup all your structure, data, stored procedures, functions, triggers, etc.
- `mysql --version`
      mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
- `cat /etc/my.cnf`

  ```
  [client]
  default-character-set = utf8mb4

  [mysql]
  default-character-set = utf8mb4

  [mysqld]
  character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
  character-set-server = utf8mb4
  init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8mb4
  collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  ```
- I'm using java client which is `'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.30'`
- My connection string is `jdbc:mysql://ip.of.database:3306/your_db_name?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&noAccessToProcedureBodies=true&autoReconnect=true`